# How to get selected qRadioButton from a qRadioButton array within QHBoxLayout

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to create a array of, say 10, radio buttons and later check which radio buttons is selected.  Here is how I do it:

creating array of radio buttons

```
a=QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
for j in range(10):
    a.addWidget(QtWidgets.QRadioButton(str(j+1))
```

check which radio button is selected

```
for j in a.children():
    if j.isChecked():
           print(j.text())
```

which never returns any text and `a.children()` is `[]`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem, you can provide a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc I corrected the problem description

Comment: no, it does not return anything to me since children() returns an empty list. the widgets that are added to a layout are not children of the layout but the widget where the layout was set up, which is why I find it strange and is the reason for my request.

Comment: @eyllanesc You are right, the description was wrong, I corrected it.  Maybe choice of using QHBoxLayout is not right, what do you suggest

Comment: I have provided a solution where I try to be as detailed as possible, so if you have any point to me. On the other hand in a previous question I see that my solution served you but you did not mark it as correct, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, layouts are not visual elements, they are elements that manage the position of the widgets they have in charge or other layouts. On the other hand, a widget is only visible if it is the children of another widget or if it is a window. So when you add a widget to a layout the parent of that widget will be the widget where the layout was established.

To verify I will use the following example:

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(w)
for j in range(10):
    lay.addWidget(QtWidgets.QRadioButton(str(j+1)))
print("children of layout: ", lay.children())
print("children of widget: ", w.children())
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

```
children of layout:  []
children of widget:  [<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout object at 0x7fbf0ee2d288>, <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QRadioButton object at 0x7fbf0ee2d1f8>, <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QRadioButton object at 0x7fbf0ee2d168>, <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QRadioButton object at 0x7fbf0ee2d0d8>, <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QRadioButton object at 0x7fbf0ee2d048>, <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QRadioButton object at 0x7fbf0ee2d828>, <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QRadioButton object at 0x7fbf0ee2d8b8>, <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QRadioButton object at 0x7fbf0e860d38>, <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QRadioButton object at 0x7fbf0e860dc8>, <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QRadioButton object at 0x7fbf0e860e58>, <PyQt5.QtWidgets.QRadioButton object at 0x7fbf0e860ee8>]
```

As you can see, the layout has no children but the w widget has as children the widgets that were added to the layout because the layout was established inside w.

---

On the other hand, the idea of a child is in the QObject as the widgets, so a QWidget can have children that are not widgets but in general they are QObject, so using the children method is a bad way to get the children widgets.

Also if you have a set of `QRadioButton` in the same layout, ie with the same parent that is the widget where the layout was established, these will be exclusive so one can only press. So to avoid this we set the autoExclusive property in False.

A very simple and pythonic solution is to use a list to store the widgets:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.radio_buttons = []
        for j in range(10):
            btn = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(str(j+1))
            btn.setAutoExclusive(False)
            hlay.addWidget(btn)
            self.radio_buttons.append(btn)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Press me")
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        lay.addWidget(button)
        lay.addLayout(hlay)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        for btn in self.radio_buttons:
            if btn.isChecked():
                print(btn.text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I believe you it works. I haven't tested it myself because in meantime and some really crazy searches I managed to find even simpler solution, which I'll provide below.

Comment: @Pygmalion The only problem with your solution is that it is not scalable, many times the layouts handle several widget and then your code would throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

After some unusually crazy searches I came to this solution:

```
for j in range(10):
    if a.itemAt(j).widget().isChecked():
        print(a.itemAt(j).widget().text())
```